Parent Link In Menu Keeps Resetting After a Draft Is Created
Since Upgrading from core 10.1.7 to 10.2.7, I've been encountering a strange issue on the site that I manage.  After creating a draft of any page, the parent link drop down keeps resetting to [main navigation], additionally the menu weight item resets to 0.  This of course causes all kinds of problems as if the page is published the URL now moves breaking access across the site.  I've been racking my brain trying to debug, but I've hit a wall.
The issue seems to occur on any page that a draft is created for.  Immediately publishing a change without a draft doesn't seem to trigger an issue, and once a page is messed up in this way, after I correct it, the issue doesn't occur again for that page.
If I review the menu item in structure -> menu -> main navigation for a page that is impacted I get the following error message:
WARNING: ARRAY_FLIP(): CAN ONLY FLIP STRING AND INTEGER VALUES, ENTRY SKIPPED IN DRUPAL\CORE\ENTITY\ENTITYSTORAGEBASE->LOADMULTIPLE() (LINE 278 OF CORE/LIB/DRUPAL/CORE/ENTITY/ENTITYSTORAGEBASE.PHP).
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadMultiple(Array) (Line: 262)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->load(NULL) (Line: 100)
Drupal\menu_link_content\Form\MenuLinkContentForm->form(Array, Object) (Line: 107)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm->buildForm(Array, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 536)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->retrieveForm('menu_link_content_menu_link_content_form', Object) (Line: 283)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object, Object) (Line: 73)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 627)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 181)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 76)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 28)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 32)
Drupal\big_pipe\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 263)
Drupal\shield\ShieldMiddleware->bypass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 219)
Drupal\shield\ShieldMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 36)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\AjaxPageState->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 704)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

It seems like something is being lost or reset when the draft is created -- if I debug MenuLinkContentForm.php, I can see things like the menu_id, parent_id and default values are all NULL, as opposed to actual entity items for pages where the issue isn't occurring.  I've yet to track down the root cause, but like I mentioned in the opening, this started after upgrading to 10.2.7
Any assistance that can be offered would be greatly appreciated!

I just (yesterday) found that a recent core upgrade caused that menu link content form to be pre-rendered twice, which meant some custom code stopped working as expected (removing fields and seemingly manipulating save values). Might be something specific to the site I was working on, but it might be worth checking that you don't have any custom code firing on that form that may be getting hit twice
